# Is it possible to restrict user not to forward the youtube video more than a set time (like live video streaming)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

This is just a curiosity,
So is it possible to stop a user not to allow forward more than a set time.

For Example: 
I have a video 20 minutes long, I have used it on my website, and I want that the user can not forward it or slide it by its progress bar [image: check Image] more than 12 minutes (or any given time).

it is possible or not?

Comment: Are you say the video must stop playing at 12 minutes or that at 12 minutes it wont allow the user to slide to later points but the video continues to play?

Comment: I want to say here, if a video is playing, and current playing time is 10 or 12 min, so user can not go forward, but he want to go backward then he can. Like live video streaming do.

Comment: Ah I see, I know there is a way to stop after a certain amount of time but I haven't come across a way to allow user to go back or prevent fast forwarding. Would be cool

Comment: @Rutendo I have created a custom solution for the same, but code is not good. Let me post it as an answer, If anyone can help me reduce the code or make it better in terms of performance.

Comment: would be very good to post your solution as I am very curious to see how it would be done

Comment: I am still working on this, you can check it here,
https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/aboqQPg
just change the time and date in "videoStartTime" this variable to see the results